# How to change precision of mpf_class after default inicialization?

Tags: c++, gmp

I need to encapsulate `mpf_class` from MPIR library into my class `A`:

```
class A
{           
    mpf_class a;    // default constructor - default precision
public:
    A(){                
        a = mpf_class(0,my_precision); // initialize a with zero, but it remains with default precision 
        mpf_class b = mpf_class(0,my_precision); // initialize local b with zero with my_precision
    }
};
```

but in the constructor I cannot initialize `a` with `my_precision`, because `operator=` does not change the precision of destination.

The only way I founded is to change default precision to `my_precision` before create object of `A`, like

```
mpf_set_default_prec(my_precision);
A my_class;
```

which works, but it is a very bad solution. So, how to create field `a` with the wanted  precision?

Comment: You already got the right answer, but I wanted to mention the `mpf_class::set_prec` function which allows you to change the precision of one variable, and the `swap` function which does what its name suggests (although with MPIR instead of GMP you may need to use mpf_swap on the result of mpf_class::get_mpf_t).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for comment, `set_prec` can also solve the problem. Actually, it is logical that such function exist, since the implementation of `operator=` does not change the precision of destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the member initialization list to initialize `a`:

```
A() : a(0, my_precision)
{ }
```

This avoids the default construction of `a`.

Comment: Thank you. I can not believe that I didn't know this.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: @Petar No! Definitely not! Questions like this help users in the future who are also looking for answers to similar problems.